# Problem with my input data structure using Torchvision RetinaNet?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, pytorch, computer-vision

I believe my input data is in the correct structure as required by the Torchvision RetinaNet, however I receive an error implying that perhaps it is not. I've included the callback and a minimal example that reproduces the problem.

This error occurs while computing loss in the classification head. It does not occur computing loss in the regression head.

This is the callback

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_1483/2833406441.py in <module>
     41 img_batch, targets_batch = retinanet_collate_fn(batch_size=2)
     42 
---> 43 outputs = model(img_batch, targets_batch)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1100         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1101                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1102             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1103         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1104         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/models/detection/retinanet.py in forward(self, images, targets)
    530 
    531             # compute the losses
--> 532             losses = self.compute_loss(targets, head_outputs, anchors)
    533         else:
    534             # recover level sizes

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/models/detection/retinanet.py in compute_loss(self, targets, head_outputs, anchors)
    394             matched_idxs.append(self.proposal_matcher(match_quality_matrix))
    395 
--> 396         return self.head.compute_loss(targets, head_outputs, anchors, matched_idxs)
    397 
    398     def postprocess_detections(self, head_outputs, anchors, image_shapes):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/models/detection/retinanet.py in compute_loss(self, targets, head_outputs, anchors, matched_idxs)
     49         # type: (List[Dict[str, Tensor]], Dict[str, Tensor], List[Tensor], List[Tensor]) -> Dict[str, Tensor]
     50         return {
---> 51             'classification': self.classification_head.compute_loss(targets, head_outputs, matched_idxs),
     52             'bbox_regression': self.regression_head.compute_loss(targets, head_outputs, anchors, matched_idxs),
     53         }

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/models/detection/retinanet.py in compute_loss(self, targets, head_outputs, matched_idxs)
    113                 foreground_idxs_per_image,
    114                 targets_per_image['labels'][matched_idxs_per_image[foreground_idxs_per_image]]
--> 115             ] = 1.0
    116 
    117             # find indices for which anchors should be ignored

IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for dimension 1 with size 1
```

Minimal example:

```
''' Adapted from example in PyTorch code '''
import torch
import torchvision
from torchvision.models.detection.anchor_utils import AnchorGenerator
from torchvision.models.detection.backbone_utils import resnet_fpn_backbone
from torchvision.models.detection import RetinaNet

''' Backbone '''
backbone = resnet_fpn_backbone('resnet18', pretrained=False, trainable_layers=4)
backbone.out_channels = 256

''' Anchor Generator '''
anchor_sizes = ((32,), (64,), (128,), (256,), (512,)) 
aspect_ratios = ((0.5, 1.0, 2.0),) * len(anchor_sizes) 
anchor_generator = AnchorGenerator(sizes=anchor_sizes, aspect_ratios=aspect_ratios)

''' Model '''
model = RetinaNet(backbone,
                  num_classes=1,
                  anchor_generator=anchor_generator)

def __getitem__():
    img = torch.rand(3, 256, 256)
    bboxes = []
    bboxes = [[15, 15, 20, 20]]*20
    bboxes = torch.FloatTensor(bboxes)
    labels = torch.LongTensor(np.ones(len(bboxes), dtype=int))
    targets = {'boxes':bboxes, 'labels':torch.LongTensor(labels)}
    return img, targets

def retinanet_collate_fn(batch_size=2):
    img_batch = []
    targets_batch = []
    for i in range(batch_size):
        img, targets = __getitem__()
        img_batch.append(img)
        targets_batch.append(targets)
    return img_batch, targets_batch
    

img_batch, targets_batch = retinanet_collate_fn(batch_size=2)

outputs = model(img_batch, targets_batch)
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved. I set num_classes = 1, so the classifier was expecting "0"s instead of "1"s. I thought the background would automatically be 0s, and my single class 1, but this is not the case.